# Calculated column from a multiple lines column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I made this formula for a calculated column that works from with single line columns, but am unable to make it work with a multiple line column.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("flight",[shipping])),"ground","flight")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known behavior. Calculated columns does not allow Multiple Lines of Text columns to be used in their formulas.

**Reference**: [SharePoint 2013 Make Calculated Column based on Custom Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386170/sharepoint-2013-make-calculated-column-based-on-custom-column)

**Workaround**: You can create a Microsoft Flow/Power Automate or SharePoint designer workflow to check the substring in your multiple lines of text field and set the custom field value accordingly.

Comment: Hi @archy321, does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will not be shown under unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

As Ganesh said,  Multiple Lines of Text columns are not supported in Calculated columns.

You can create SharePoint designer workflow to achieve you requirement, using if condition and set a field to value in the current list action.